# How to print sql statement with its values while using parameters

Tags: c#, .net, oracle

I am looking to log the sql statement with the actual values that replace the paremeters. How do I get this string? thanks!

```
var sql = @"INSERT INTO Barcode (BarcodeKey, Barcode, BarcodeType, TableKey, RegistrationDate, 
UserKey) " +  @"VALUES (:barcodekey, :barcode, :barcodetype, :tablekey, :registrationdate, :userkey)";

        using (var con = GetOracleConnection())
        {

            var cmd = new OracleCommand
            {
                Connection = con,
                CommandText = sql,
                CommandType = CommandType.Text,
                BindByName = true
            };

            cmd.Parameters.Add("barcodekey", barcodeKey);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("barcode", newBarcode.Barcode ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("barcodetype", (int)newBarcode.BarcodeType);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("tablekey", newBarcode.TableKey ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("registrationdate", newBarcode.RegistrationDate ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("userkey", newBarcode.UserKey ?? (object)DBNull.Value);

            try
            {
                var result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Logging($"SQL: {cmd.CommandText}");
            }
```

Comment: have did you consider log4net? https://stackify.com/log4net-guide-dotnet-logging/

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL Profiler for for tracing, recreating, and troubleshooting problems in MS SQL Server

Comment: you have to loop through all the parameters to get their values and concatenate it with the command text